# springfox - swagger 2 - How to set type of global parameter

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

i'm using swagger 2.5.0 with spring boot to generate a api doc.
I have configured a global header parameter like this:

```
myDocket.globalOperationParameters(return Arrays.asList(
        new ParameterBuilder()
            .name("version")
            .description("Version of the api. Starting with 1.")
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("integer"))
            .parameterType("path")
            .defaultValue("1")
            .required(true)
            .build()))
```

The problem is, that it generate this apidoc.json:

> ...."parameters":[{"name":"version","in":"path","description":"Version of
>   the api. Starting with
>   1.","required":true,"type":"ref","default":"1"}],.....

The problem is the **"type":"ref"** . Swagger editor says that this is invalid.

How can i get swagger to generate **"type":"string"** ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `.modelRef(new ModelRef("integer"))` to `.modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))`.